# SQL How to get the result from the statement faster?

Tags: sql, select, join, union

How could I get this SQL statement smaller, like only use the WHERE once somewhere, to get the result faster? Thanks!

```
SELECT p.model, pc.price FROM Product AS p
JOIN PC AS pc
  ON pc.model = p.model
WHERE p.maker='B'

UNION
SELECT p.model, lp.price FROM Product AS p
JOIN Laptop AS lp
  ON p.model = lp.model
WHERE p.maker='B'

UNION
SELECT p.model, pr.price FROM Product AS p
JOIN Printer AS pr
  ON p.model = pr.model
WHERE p.maker='B'
```

**Edit**: I want it to be faster.

Comment: very easy to read as it is.  Why change it?

Comment: I taught the maybe there is a better/faster way to get the result.

Comment: Aside from normalizing into a single products table and having an identifier that designates type...

Comment: compact code <> faster results

Comment: You can make it much faster just by replacing each `union` with `union all`.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably leave it as it is, unless you plan on adding more to it. But as a literal answer to your question:

```
select pr.model,
       case
         when pc.price is not null then
          pc.price
         when lp.price is not null then
          lp.price
         when pt.price is not null then
          pt.price
         else
          null
       end as price
  from product pr
  left join pc
    on pr.model = pc.model
  left join laptop lp
    on pr.model = lp.model
  left join printer pt
    on pr.model = pt.model
 where pr.maker = 'B'
```

Comment: You can replace the `case` with just `coalesce(pc.price, lp.price, pt.price)`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to speed up your query is to replace each `union` with `union all` and then add the following indexes:

```
create index product_maker_model on produce(maker, model);
create index pc_model_price on pc(model, price);
create index laptop_model_price on laptop(model, price);
create index printer_model_price on printer(model, price);
```

The query is:

```
SELECT p.model, pc.price
FROM Product p JOIN
     PC pc
     ON pc.model = p.model
WHERE p.maker = 'B'
UNION ALL
SELECT p.model, lp.price
FROM Product p JOIN
     Laptop lp
     ON p.model = lp.model
WHERE p.maker = 'B'
UNION ALL
SELECT p.model, pr.price
FROM Product p JOIN
     Printer pr
     ON p.model = pr.model;
WHERE p.maker = 'B';
```

The same indexes will speed up the `left outer join` version as well.  Which is faster depends on a variety of factors, but the left outer join version might perform better.

Answer (score -1):

Try a CTE.

Psuedo.   Not in front of a terminal.

```
With product as
(
Select fields from PC union all
Select fields from laptop union all
Select fields from printers
)
Select fields from product where maker = b
```

Comment: Make sure your fields match.  Add a semicolon in front of the with.  Maybe someone can format that as code for me.  Sorry I am on my phone.

Comment: even though not tagged as such I guess the OP must be using sql-server?

Comment: As the OP wanted `faster ways to get the result` - would this help or not?

Comment: See my comment on the main post.  Aside from normalization.  This MAY depending on how the optimizer a sees it.  Not a guarantee though.  Indexes and normalization is the ticket.